# Overlapping an equation on a figure - Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm looking for a way to overlap an equation on a figure in Microsoft Word. So far I found only how to move an equation to the left/right side or to the center:

[image]

Comment: maybe put the equation into a text box

Comment: Hi @Bodo thank you very much for your helpful solution.